# angularjs+python(Flask) file upload to server

Tags: python, angularjs, file-upload, flask, form-data

I am developing a web app using angular, python and Flask. 
In my app there is a form where the user need to enter some data and to upload his photo.
I want to implement the file upload to the server using angular.
I saw that I need to use the FormData() and to bind the data from the HTML to angular using "watch".
The javascript part is clear.
I don't understand how can I get the data from the Python side.

This is my HTML -

```
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-submit="submitGuideDetailsForm()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="usr">Add your photo:</label>
    <input type='file' class="form-control" name='file' onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadFile(this.files)">
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my angular -

```
 $scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
            $scope.file = new FormData();
            $scope.file.append("file", files[0]);
        };
 $scope.submitGuideDetailsForm= function() {
     $http.post('/uploadFile', $scope.file, {
           headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
           transformRequest: angular.identity
          }).success(function(results) 
           {   
              $log.log('success load file')
           }).error(function(error) 
           {
              $log.log('error load file!!!!!')
              $log.log(error);
           });
       };
```

I want to get the file on the server side, using python and flask -

```
@app.route('/uploadFile', methods=['POST'])
def uploadFile():
  json_data = request.json
  print(json_data)
  status = 'success'
  return jsonify({'result': status})
```

I don't know how to get the data from the 'request' object.
`request.json` does not work.

Please advice me what am I doing wrong.
How can I get the data from the 'request' object?
Do I need to encode the data to a file?
How do I send the data back to client? Do I need to encode it back?
I did not find a full example using angular and python/flask uploading a file to server, saving it and than downloading it to the client.
Thanks a lot,
Dina

Comment: try `request.file` or `request.files`

Answer (score 1):

the file can be get by`file = request.files['file']` 
after that,
you can get the filename by `file.filename.encode("utf8")`

Comment: Thanks man! that helped me deal with one of the quite errors I was having

Answer (score 0):

The command 'request.files' work
The gets me the following object -

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('file', <FileStorage:
 u'12132638_10153196350425732_1151540092606190338_o.jpg'
 ('image/jpeg')>)])
```

I don't understand how can I save it on the server.
How do I get only the file name out of this object
And how do I send it back to the client side?

Thanks a lot, Dina

Answer (score 0):

Use request.files and .filename atrribute

```
file = request.files['file']
fileName = file.filename

#to store it on server use getvalue() and write it to the file object
filedata = file.getvalue()
with open('abc.png') as f:
    f.write(filedata)
```